# What does אה"ת stand for?

Tags: words, jewish-books, acronyms

What do these rashei teivos stand for? See, for example,  the Dikdukei Sofrim [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=aztAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=%D7%90%D7%94"%D7%AA&source=bl&ots=zM9Fs3B_AC&sig=TrdNEYyvk-NQhEU3_pNEz9OpOu0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwii2aetuf7ZAhUOj1kKHf61CcsQ6AEwCHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D7%90%D7%94"%D7%AA&f=false).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is אגדות התלמוד, as stated in the *Introduction* to *Dikdukei Sofrim*. It is also mentioned in the list of *Rashei Teivos* in the *Oz VeHadar Gemara*. The Dikdukei Sofrim describes the book as follows:

> ספר אגדות התלמוד הוא קובץ כולל כל האגדות שבש"ס כעין ספר העין יעקב בלי
>   פירוש רק פירוש מקצת המלות ונתחבר מספרדי אחד טרם שנתחבר העין יעקב ונדפס
>   באותיות רש"י בקושטנטינא בשנת רע"א במדנת פאליא קטן והעין יעקב מביאו
>   בהקדמתו וכתב שם "וגם עתה ראיתי בעיני אחרי אשר החלותי לסדר ולכתוב החבור
>   הזה כי כבר קדמני חכם ספרדי אשר כתב על ספר מיוחד כל מדרשי התלמוד וכבר
>   הסכימו להדפיסו אנשים חכמים ונבונים העומדים על מלאכת הדפוס בעיר גדולה
>   של חכמים וסופרים קונסטאנטינא ומלאה הארץ דעה מאותם הספרים כי התלמידים
>   והתרים והסוחרים קנו רבים מהם ולא בדמים יקרים" וכוונתו הוא על הספר הזה